# After migrating wordpress site some pages redirecting to old domain

Tags: wordpress, http, web, vs-web-site-project

I just migrated the my website from my old domain to new domain. Its migrated but when I am clicking on something like pages or category its redirecting me to the old site with this error:

> The site can't provide a secure connection. shopskart.in sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhDG3.png)

I also did these changes in wp-conf and wp-options but still I am getting same issue. Someone said its because its forcing site to https due to SSL I had but now I don't have SSL and don't want one right now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied the old SSL file to your new site, and it's still active. You should disable it. Also check if there's any setting (in backend or database) pointing to https in stead of http, since you won't be using a secure connection anymore (Why not? You should!). Check the htaccess file as well! If the problem still occurs try clearing your browsercache.

Answer (score 0):

From where i can find the ssl file. Or code. Actually the website was created by my developer and now he refused to give the data when i asked him. So i migraded using wp plugins and dont know where he pasted the ssl certificate.